# Are "this" and "these" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, singular, verb-agreement

> What **does this** mean?
>
> What **do this** mean?
>
> What **does these** mean?
>
> What **do these** mean?

When I should use **do** or **does** before **this** and **these**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct versions with *this* and *these* are:

> What **does** **this** mean?

Here *this* is singular, so you use *does*. For instance, if you want to ask about a single question, so you would say:

> What does this question mean?

Next:

> What **do** **these** mean?

Likewise, *these* indicates plural objects in number. So you use *do*. Following the previous example, you would ask:

> What do these questions mean?